# Autowiring two different beans of same class

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I have a class which wraps a connection pool, the class gets its connection details from a spring configuration as shown below:

```xml
<bean id="jedisConnector" class="com.legolas.jedis.JedisConnector" init-method="init" destroy-method="destroy">
    <property name="host" value="${jedis.host}" />
    <property name="port" value="${jedis.port}" />
</bean>
```

This bean is later used in a service and is autowired with the `@Autowire` annotation.

My question is, how can i duplicate this bean and give it different connection details and then `@Autowire` it in the service.
meaning In addition to above I will have :

```xml
<bean id="jedisConnectorPOD" class="com.legolas.jedis.JedisConnector" init-method="init" destroy-method="destroy">
    <property name="host" value="${jedis.pod.host}" />
    <property name="port" value="${jedis.pod.port}" />
</bean>
```

and in the service:

```
@Autowired //bean of id jedisConnector
JedisConnector beanA;

@Autowired //bean of id jedisConnectorPOD
JedisConnector beanB;
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can combine `@Autowired` with `@Qualifier`, but in this case instead of `@Autowired`, I suggest using `@Resource`:

```
@Resource(name="jedisConnector")
JedisConnector beanA;

@Resource(name="jedisConnectorPOD")
JedisConnector beanB;
```

or even simpler:

```
@Resource
JedisConnector jedisConnector;

@Resource
JedisConnector jedisConnectorPOD;
```

Comment: Also, if also using a JEE app server (e.g. JBoss), it will also try to process @Resource and everything will break.

Comment: @OrangeDog: I use this with JBoss without any issues.

Comment: @skaffman - The first one or the second one? JBoss 5 will definitely try to satisfy the resources even if Spring already has done. It might get it right, but you still probably don't want it to try.

Comment: I used the second option with tomcat and spring at it worked fine.

Comment: Can you please justify.. why 2nd approach is suited in this case ?

Answer (score 41):

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("jedisConnector")
JedisConnector beanA;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("jedisConnectorPOD")
JedisConnector beanB;
```

Comment: Based on http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s11.html This is the most correct answer.

Comment: This doesn't work for me when the beans are defined in XML with `<bean id="..."`.

Comment: You also need to add the Qualifier annotation above the bean class so it knows which is which

Comment: @Rstar37 no you don't. The argument is the bean name.