# Why does two transaction manager instances throw an exception?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-batch

I'm using Spring batch and JPA, and anytime I want to save a bean, I have the following problem with my Spring Batch and JPA transaction manager.
Anytime I am trying to save a bean, I get this Exception (whole stacktrace):

```
09.09.2014 13:38:07 [[ERROR] org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep [http-bio-8080-exec-1]] Encountered an error executing step billrecordRe
adStep in job billrecordReadJob
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionMana
ger] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: batchTransactionManager,applicationTransactionManager
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:313)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.determineTransactionManager(TransactionAspectSupport.java:337)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:252)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
at com.blang.dao.ExportedReportDAO$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5a8e689e.addReport(<generated>)
at com.blang.services.ExportedRecordService.storeRecord(ExportedRecordService.java:19)
at com.blang.service.exports.BillrecordExporter.execute(RecordExporter.java:61)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271)
at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:198)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:162)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:141)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:304)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128)
at com.tk.service.exports.BatchLauncher.launch(BatchLauncher.java:46)
at com.tk.controller.ServiceController.exportRecords(ServiceController.java:304)
at com.tk.controller.ServiceController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$97cea7bb.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:52)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:52)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
at com.blang.controller.ServiceController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1e76d6cc.exportDocument(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749
)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
09.09.2014 13:38:07 [[ INFO] org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher [http-bio-8080-exec-1]] Job: [FlowJob: [name=recordRe
adJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{filterValue=, customerNumber=XxXxXxX, costs=null, x1=null, x2=null, y1=null, y2=null,
exportMode=CSV, sessionId=6njkdfdjhffhffffsdss}] and the following status: [FAILED]
```

The two transaction managers are defined in my Spring config XMLs. This is my application-context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core"
xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core
http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core.xsd
http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet
http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd"
default-autowire="byName">

<context:annotation-config />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="applicationTransactionManager" />

<jee:jndi-lookup id="prodDataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/mysqldb"
    expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

<!-- JPA -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="appPersistenceUnit" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="prodDataSource" />
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="com.tk.servicetool.exports.CustomHibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="applicationTransactionManager"  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>


<!-- Spring Batch -->
<bean id="jobRepository"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean" >
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="applicationTransactionManager" /> 
</bean>

<bean id="jobLauncher"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
</bean>
```

and my batch-config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"  
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd">

<bean id="batchTransactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

<bean id="billrecordExporter" class="com.blang.services.exports.RrecordExporter" />

<batch:job id="RecordReadJob" job-repository="jobRepository">
    <batch:step id="RecordReadStep">
        <batch:tasklet ref="recordExporter"
            transaction-manager="batchTransactionManager" />
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<bean id="batchLauncher" class="com.blang.services.exports.BatchLauncher">
    <property name="jobLauncher" ref="jobLauncher" />
    <property name="job" ref="recordReadJob" />
</bean>
```

The next code shows my DAo, where the exception is thrown from:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import com.blang.bean.ExportedReport;

@Repository
public class ExportedReportDAO
{
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DocumentDAO.class);

@Transactional
public void addReport(ExportedReport report) {
  entityManager.persist(report);
}

}
```

In fact of too less information, just tell me.
If there is someone, who can help me with that problem, I would be very thankful.

Many thanks in advance!

Kind regards

Comment: I think this here can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462466/autowiring-two-different-beans-of-same-class

Comment: can you paste the complete stacktrace? issue is with bean injection, there are 2 beans of same types so spring does not know which one to inject

Comment: You have a `batchTransactionManager` and a `applicationTransactionManager`

Comment: @AVolpe Well, yes I have 2, because I think I need 1 for the JPA transactions and the otherone for the batch transactions.

Comment: @UweAllner I have no idea where in my DAo I should use the qualifier annotation.

Comment: @zerocool I have posted the whole stacktrace in my previous question.

Comment: you need to qualify which transaction manager SB has to use

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci Thank you, but can you give me an example, please?

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci Well, ok. that is something Uwe Allner has mentioned before but if I write Qualifier("applicationTransactionManager") under the Transactional annotation, it wouldn't fix the problem. The exception is still the same.

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci Where do I mix it? I am configuring everything in my XML files. There is no configuration in any java class...

Comment: try specify http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#value--. but usually @Transactional for SB method should be avoided because transaction management is done by SB

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci This: Transactional("applicationTransactionmanager") is not possible, nor this: Transactional(value="applicationTransactionmanager") The Transactional annotation expects a TxType as value.

Comment: Ok, I got it. There are two transaction managers. I had to chose this one: org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional instead of the JPA transaction manager (javax.transaction.Transactional). Thank you @LucaBassoRici ! You gave me a good hint. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to take the right transactional annotation in the DAO class.
I used

```
javax.transaction.Transactional
```

,which causes the exception. I changed to this one:

```
org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
```

and it works fine now!